# Error on return of templated item in arraylist

Tags: java

I am have this code where I am getting an error but I don't know why, I am using templates and am returning items that implement 'MasterGetter' but I get the error that they are incompatible types

```
private <T extends MasterGetter, A extends AnimalInterface> T returnClosestObject(A a){ 
      a.findClosest();                                                        
      for(Squirrel s : squirrels){                                               
          if(s.get_col() == a.get_closest_col() && s.get_row() == a.get_closest_row()){
            return s;                                                       
          }                                                                   
      }                                                                       

      for(Tree t : trees){                                                       
          if(t.get_col() == a.get_closest_col() && t.get_row() == a.get_closest_row()){
           return t;                                                       
          }                                                                      
      }                                                                       


}
```

Squirrel implements `AnimalInterface` and `MasterGetter`
Tree implements only `MasterGetter`

`squirrels` is an ArrayList of Squirrel objects
`trees is` an ArrayList of Tree objects

Thanks for any help on this :)

Comment: What exactly does your error say? Is the compiler complaining about your return statement?

Comment: It says that there is an error on the object returned (s/t), it is on the return statement, the error is that they are 'incompatible types'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature

```
private <T extends MasterGetter, A extends AnimalInterface> T returnClosestObject(A a)
```

is not what you want. Since both `Squirrel` and `Tree` implement `MasterGetter`, `T` could be either of those classes.

Since `T` could be `Squirrel`, `return t;` doesn't make sense (a tree is not a squirrel).

Since `T` could be `Tree`, `return s;` doesn't make sense (a squirrel is not a tree).

A more sensible signature is simply:

```
private MasterGetter returnClosestObject(AnimalInterface a)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! When is the time to use <T extends MasterGetter>?

Comment: When the type is needed more than once in the signature/return type. If it is only needed once you can use wildcards, or something simple like in this case.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Thanks so much for your help!